# working 'types' definition files, anyone?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

We're using Tabulator-tables in a large Angular project and I cannot seem to find a usable definition files.

I've tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/tabulator-tables which seems updated etc but it results in lots of errors in my IDE and the project will not compile as a result. There are many errors even though the compilation worked before I added the types package. Its  pointless and impractical to add many @ts-ignore comments.

Be advised - I took notice to use the same version of the type definition package as installed in my project (v4.2.2). I assume the problem is with the automatic generation of the above package - the resulting .d.ts file is not usable as a result.

Please correct me if I'm wrong and any help in integrating definition files will be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Have you tried using the library directly ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabulator-tables

Comment: So when I do `import * as Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables';` in my Angular project (its Angular) I get 'Tabulator' type. But how do I get, for example, CellComponent type?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't have types definition

Comment: As far as I see - you're right.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with adding TypeScript typings on Angular project and here's what i did:

1. encapsulated Tabulator inside Angular component (data-grid.component.ts in my case);
2. `npm install @types/tabulator-tables`
3. created file data-grid.component.d.ts with:

```
    declare module 'tabulator-tables' {
      export = Tabulator;
    }
```

4. *the key thing*: removed `import Tabulator from 'tabulator-tables'` from file data-grid.component.ts

And it's worked.

Comment: I can no longer test your solution but it looks worth the check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A full set of TypeScript Typings can be found in the ***@types/tabulator-tables*** npm package

```
npm install @types/tabulator-tables
```

An example of how to use the typings in a project can be found [here](https://github.com/Jojoshua/TypedTabulator)

The [Language Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/language#typescript) includes more information on the available typings

Answer (score 0):

I already wrote an answer for this issue, not good enough in my opinion, but some people upvoted it as right, so I decided to leave it as it is and write a new one.

There is some issues with adding types for tabulator, this is because type annotations not being exported, but there is a way to use them.

After installation of types for tabulator (`npm install --save @types/tabulator-tables`), you should open (or create it, if it's not exists) file `index.d.ts` inside directory `src`, and copy following code into it:

```
declare module 'tabulator-tables' {
  export = Tabulator;
}
```

You need to ensure that you have `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` inside `compilerOptions` of file `tsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.app.json` (depends on your project), and `tsconfig.spec.ts` (it needs for unit testing).

*Very important* to unload and start over `ng serve` after editing of tsconfig.

After that all typings should work. Just in case I created simple [Angular example](https://github.com/Karoshee/AngularTypedTabulator), hope this helps.